# Enter main class in run/debug configurations

Tags: java

I can't seem to find a "main class" for my run/debug configurations. I watched a video and everything is set to default for them. I am using jdk 17, javafx and placed everything else correctly. Here is the photo: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRqkT.png) I tried setting it to my project files, and other things. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you haven't **written** the main class.  Did you?  Does it have the required method or class signature?

Comment: I am very new to this and I dont know what a "main" class is.  I have a good idea what your talking about but I am not sure.

Comment: Read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm.  Look at the first method in the example.

Comment: Ok, I  got it all figured out. I edited the config and led it to the class that starts the application with the main method. Now it reads me an error message. Here it is:  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe" --module-path C:\Users\yozsh\Downloads\openjfx-17.0.1_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-17.0.1\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ 
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module com.example.beluxfx not found

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: OK ... so now you seem to have gotten yourself into a knot with modules.  Read https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/.  In particular read the relevant sections for JavaFX with Intellij.  Given that it can't find your module file, I guess you trying to develop a non-modular project.

Comment: yes I am creating non-modular, I've read over the text and can't seem to find anything. I will be finding for solutions in the meantime.

Comment: Well, if you are creating a non-modular app, it shouldn't be looking for your app's module file.   Double-check.  Compare the steps for a modular and non-modular cases to see the differences, and make sure that you have followed the non-modular steps.  Alternatively ... create a module file and be done with it.  It looks like modular is simpler / cleaner.

Comment: What’s the difference? Are there any benefits? Does it make the program better?

Comment: Well the most obvious benefit would be that you are not stuck on this problem. Google for "what are the benefits of Java modules".